# Django want to display help_text

Tags: python, html, django, forms, tags

Hello I would like to display this help text in my model forms called alternate_id. However I seem to be having trouble with this. It might be what I have written in my response context.

forms.py

```
alternate_id = forms.CharField(label = 'Client no', max_length = 400, required = False, help_text = 'Valid wildcard search is in the format *XX, *XX*, XX*')
```

views.py

```
def search_item(request, client_id = 0):
    # search form code
    return render_to_response('search_items.html', {'form':form, 'form.alternate_id':form.alternate_id}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

search_items.html

```
<form action="." method="post">
        <fieldset class="model">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {{ form.alternate_id.help_text }}
        </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try removing `form.alternate_id':form.alternate_id` from your context dict. The form itself should contain the alternate_id field and its help text.

Comment: Worked. I guess the only only thing that is bothering me is that the help text is not written in a structured position. I guess only if you build a customse form would work only. Thanks anyway.